# Ventas por día en un mes y año específico - SQL

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos

deseo obtener las ventas realizadas por dia en un determinado mes y año, eso lo pude hacer; pero si en un dia del mes no se hizo venta no muestra.

Este el codigo SQL:

```
SELECT  
    DATEPART(DAY,VMP.fechaPago) as fecha,  
    ISNULL(SUM(VMP.totalPago),0) as total  
FROM VentasMatriculasPagos VMP  
WHERE VMP.estado = 1  
    AND YEAR(VMP.fechaPago) = 2017  
    AND MONTH(VMP.fechaPago) = 8  
    AND VMP.idSede = 1--@idSede  
GROUP BY DATEPART(DAY,VMP.fechaPago)
```

[image: Este es el resultado]

Lo que yo quiero obtener es:

1 = 0
2 = 0
3 = 1405.0
.
.
.
Hasta el ultimo dia del mes

Comment: Tienes disponible una tabla de "Días", simplemente con un registro por día?

Comment: ¿Solo quieres para un determinado periodo o deben ser para varios?, por ejemplo en tu consulta solo consideras 201708 (Agosto del 2017).

Comment: es solo por mes - anio... eso lo mando como parametro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes generar los dias del mese en una cte y unirlos a tu consulta principal para generar los resultados del mes:

```
--Generamos los dias del mes
DECLARE @mes TINYINT
DECLARE @ano INT
SET
@mes = 8;
SET
@ano = 2017
;WITH CTE_DIAS
AS
(SELECT dateadd(month,@mes-1,dateadd(year,@ano,0)) D
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, D)FROM CTE_DIAS
    WHERE D < dateadd(month,@mes,dateadd(year,@ano,0))-1
)SELECT DATEPART(day, c.D) AS DIAS
INTO #DT
FROM
CTE_DIAS c

SELECT  
    DATEPART(DAY,VMP.fechaPago) as fecha,  
    ISNULL(SUM(VMP.totalPago),0) as total  
INTO #VMP
FROM VentasMatriculasPagos VMP  
WHERE VMP.estado = 1  
    AND YEAR(VMP.fechaPago) = 2017  
    AND MONTH(VMP.fechaPago) = 8  
    AND VMP.idSede = 1--@idSede  
GROUP BY DATEPART(DAY,VMP.fechaPago)  
--Unimos los resultados
SELECT D.DIAS , ISNULL(V.total, 0) AS TOTAL
FROM #DT D
    LEFT JOIN #VMP V ON V.fecha = D.DIAS

DROP TABLE #DT
DRIO TABLE #VMP
```

Tendrias que pasar de parametro el mes y año en variables al procedimiento, ya para ponerlo de forma dinamica de acuerdo a las fechas de tu consulta

**Nota: Lo realice en un sketch rapido asi que se puede mejorar la consulta**

Saludos

Comment: si claro el mes y año son parametros...lo voy a probar

Answer (score 0):

Algo tarde, pero te envío otra opción mas sencilla:

```
DECLARE @Mes TINYINT = 8;
DECLARE @Anio INT =2017;
DECLARE @dia TINYINT = 1;
DECLARE @PrimerDiaMesActual DATETIME = cast(convert(datetime,convert(varchar(10),@Anio) + '-' + convert(varchar(10),@mes) + '-' + convert(varchar(10),@dia), 101) as date);
DECLARE @UtimoDiaMesActual DATETIME = DATEADD(day,-1,DATEADD(MONTH,1,@PrimerDiaMesActual))
DECLARE @UltimoDia INT = DATEPART(DAY, @UtimoDiaMesActual);
```

CREATE TABLE #Fechas (fecha DATETIME)

WHILE (@dia <= @ultimoDia)
BEGIN
    PRINT @dia 
    INSERT INTO #Fechas (fecha) VALUES (cast(convert(datetime,convert(varchar(10),@Anio) + '-' + convert(varchar(10),@mes) + '-' + convert(varchar(10),@dia), 101) as date))
    SET @dia=@dia+1;
END 
SELECT F.fecha, ISNULL((SELECT SUM(VMP.totalPago) from VentasMatriculasPagos VMP  WHERE VMP.fechaPago=F.fecha),0) AS Total FROM #Fechas F

DROP Table #Fechas

Comment: Oh gracias voy a probarlo